# Gmail API quota units cost

Tags: gmail-api

We are building a service that utilizes the Gmail API. In order to understand our costs as we scale, I would like to know how much it costs to use the Gmail API. I've followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota through to the point at which it says:

> If you have enabled billing for your project [we have], clicking Quota
>   takes you to a page where you can view and change quota-related
>   settings.

The only option on that page for changing our daily quota is to "Apply for higher quota"; however, clicking that opens a window that says:

> Please be sure to review the existing quota limits to confirm you need
>   more than the daily default.... If you simply have a question on limits, please ask it on the Stack
>   Overflow forum

Thus, I am asking here: what is the cost per API unit when one's needs exceed the daily free quota?

Comment: The API isn't even marked as billable so not sure how you could have enabled billing for it.  If you are using your existing quota or are getting close and want to ask for more, I think best place is to ask on the quota request form.  There's no "price sheet" or anything for buying extra quota--that's handled through the "Apply for higher quota" spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you @EricDeFriez. To answer your question on how I enabled billing, I followed the "enabled billing" link in "If you have enabled billing" on https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota and followed the instructions enumerated under "To enable billing for your project, do the following" on the resulting page. We are nowhere close to reaching our limit, but are making product decisions now that require us to have a sense of what the API usage costs are going to be.

Comment: Ah I see, so you've enabled billing for your developer project.  In any case, the Gmail API isn't marked as "billable".  It's free with a limit.  So yeah, it's quite reasonable to make requests for higher quota to provision for migration/growth over the next few quarters.

Comment: Thank you @EricDeFriez. If you want to post that as an answer instead of a comment, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @ whoever downvoted: how is this post "an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The API isn't marked as "billable" meaning it's free up to a limit and there's no set/published pricing above that.   If you are using your existing quota or are getting close and want to ask for more, I think best place is to ask on the quota request form.  It's quite reasonable to ask for quota to provision for a few quarters of growth IMO and if you're migrating from some other API (e.g. IMAP, atom feed, DOM hacking) then obviously that should be quite reasonable to provision all that beforehand as well.