# Integrate Gmail into Java app with OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, google-api-java-client, google-oauth

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388256/integrate-google-login-into-java-stand-alone-app) 8 days ago with no reply. I'll try to ask better:

I'm trying to integrate a Gmail login feature into my desktop java program. Upon the very first launch, the user will be required to login/create an account. The option to "remember me" should be available afterwards. Users need to login so that the app can search their inbox for emails containing attachments, and then download one or more attachments. No emails are ever sent.

[OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) seems like a reliable API, but I'm confused about 3 things:

1) **Pricing:** The link [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/HD5GEoGfDi8) seems to mention there's no charge for the OAuto 2.0 API, regardless of whether it's used for commercial purposes or not. Do you know if this is correct or how I can verify it?

2) **Legality:** Is it legal to make money from software that uses Google's OAuth 2.0 API? Like I said, the app will only be logging into a user's email to download an attachment from a particular email.

3) **Implemenation:** Is the OAuth API the most reliable/efficient method? My rationale was to allow Google to handle the privacy and security issues so to avoid storing encrypted login data on user's PC. This is what I'm aiming for visually:

[image: demo]

Comment: Someone from Google needs to answer authoritatively about pricing and such, but my understanding is that it's free and legal for you to use it.  You'll still need to deal with security issues since your app will need to store a refresh token.

Comment: Thanks Bill, further research identified the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=en) as an alternative instead of using JavaMail. This seems like a superior route to take, would you agree? If I go with the API, does the need for storing the refresh token still apply? As for pricing, the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26657907/4594511) says it's free up to a limit. I'm assuming this is for commercial use too.

Comment: I have no experience with the Gmail API.  If you only ever want to work with Gmail and no other mail servers, it might be a reasonable alternative.  I think you'll still need to store the refresh token on the client device.